# How to protect a payload assuming we don't have SSL?

Tags: security, jwe, jose, nacl-cryptography

Say I want Bob to be able to send Alice a message using her public key over a `curl -X POST http://$DOMAIN/...` type endpoint. There are step by step instructions for this use case using "nacl" and [step-cli](https://smallstep.com/docs/tutorials)'s `step crypto nacl box`, however I am confused how to realise this using practically in a NodeJS / Express app.

The popular [node-jose](https://github.com/cisco/node-jose) package has no mention of "nacl" aka salt.

Should I be using JSON Web Encryption (JWE) instead?

What is the content-type for the encrypted message?

There doesn't seem to be super clear examples from https://github.com/cisco/node-jose#keys-used-for-encrypting-and-decrypting how to do this using Web http between "Bob" & "Alice". I.e. where is the fetching of the public key? Is it `http://$DOMAIN/.well-known/keys`?

Comment: To achieve this both side would need to know the encryption key. I am not sure this is the right solution. Any reason why you don't have a SSL? if it is the cost then it might be worth looking at this: https://letsencrypt.org/

Comment: It's not about cost, it's about not trusting the transport layer and a bit of a thought experiment.